# Can IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT automatically bind to a Link Local address?

Tags: c, unix

If I use `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` or `::` to `bind (2)` an IPv6 socket, could it end up being bound to a link local address?

I'm wondering if this can happen because I'm learning server socket programming with the UNIX C API. If the above were to happen, that would make the server inaccessible from the outside world, wouldn't it?

Or maybe I misunderstood and binding a socket to `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` and then calling `listen` actually listens on all IPs of all interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> calling listen actually listens on all IPs of all interfaces

Yes, that's correct. Using IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT will bind the socket to *all* interfaces (which includes e.g. link local and loopback addresses)

Comment: Thanks. May I ask how you know about this? Is this documented somewhere?